# Hashbang url in IE8 gives 404 on Angularjs routing

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-8

I am using angularjs with MVC4, the page loads fine on chrome on route navigation. However if I do the same in IE8 it gives a 404 error. 
Any ideas on What I should be doing to get it working on IE8?

Note:
I am using angularjs version: v1.2.16 and 
I have HTMLMode set to true.

I get that IE8 doesnt support HTML5 and so the url that it tried to go to is:

http://urldomain.com/#!/UI/CellRequest

But on chrome the url navigates to

http://urldomain.com/UI/CellRequest

Answer (score 0):

Try then below code.

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Let us know if it works.

We also created this website - http://www.itslayer.com/

We are getting problem in Ajax base Googlebot crawl. Anyone please let us know where can we test it.